# Parse variables from querystring in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

I have the following querystring:

```
"active_tab=delivered&active_tab=all&active_tab=delivered&active_tab=outstanding
&active_tab=delivered&active_tab=outstanding&active_tab=all&active_tab=delivered&active_tab=outstanding&title_filter=conformance&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=packaging
&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=all&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=all&title_filter=packaging&title_filter=conformance&title_filter=packaging
&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=packaging&title_filter=ordered"
```

How would I parse the final `title_filter` ("ordered") and `active_tab` ("delivered") from the above querystring? Also, if that querystring variable doesn't exist, have it = `""`

Comment: Is that all one query string?  It's got the same key in there multiple times!

Comment: `explode("&", $array);` while looping through array; `explode("=", $element);` each element of the first array...do stuff with the tokens...

Comment: I wrote this a while back, you can see if it works for you: https://gist.github.com/3528917

Comment: Regex may be worth exploring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @crush that's PHP, question deals with JS.

Comment: Oh, thought I clicked my PHP filter. LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = {};

var largeString = "active_tab=delivered&active_tab=all&active_tab=delivered&active_tab=outstanding&active_tab=delivered&active_tab=outstanding&active_tab=all&active_tab=delivered&active_tab=outstanding&title_filter=conformance&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=packaging&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=all&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=all&title_filter=packaging&title_filter=conformance&title_filter=packaging&title_filter=delivering&title_filter=packaging&title_filter=ordered";

largeString.split('&').forEach(function(keyValue){
    var kvp = p.split('=');
    query[kvp[0]]= kvp[1];
});
```

if you need to support arrays:

```
largeString.split('&').forEach(function(keyValue){
    var kvp = keyValue.split('=');

    if(kvp[0] in query){
        if(typeof(query[kvp[0]] === 'string')){
            query[kvp[0]] = [query[kvp[0]]];
        }
        query[kvp[0]].push(kvp[1]);
    }else{
        query[kvp[0]] = kvp[1];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the querystring to remove duplicates and then I did:

```
var active_tab = window.location.search.split('active_tab=')[1].split('&')[0]
var title_filter = window.location.search.split('title_filter=')[1].split('&')[0]
```